# Python: write files from lists based on match

Tags: python, python-3.x

please help.  i am trying to write separate files from list of lists based on a string match.

Below list X has 3 sub-lists, and based on match from filter, i want to filter the lines and write them to separate files.

```
X = ['apple,banana,fruits,orange', 'dog,cat,animals,horse', 'mouse,elephant,animals,peacock']

filter = (fruits, animals)
```

from lists in X, i want to write csv files separately based on match found in `filter`.

Tried below incomplete code:

```
def write(Y):
    temp = []
    for elem in Y:
        for n in filter:
            if n in elem:
                temp.append(elem)
```

expected output:

```
cat fruits.csv:
apple,banana,fruits,orange

cat animals.csv
dog,cat,animals,horse
mouse,elephant,animals,peacock
```

Please help or advice best method to do this.

THANKS in advance.

Comment: So where is fruits and animals coming from in ```filter = (fruits, animals)```?

Comment: Yes Rashid.. they are matched in List mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary from your list with keys as filenames and then iterate the dictionary to write to file:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

X = ['apple,banana,fruits,orange', 'dog,cat,animals,horse', 'mouse,elephant,animals,peacock']
filter = ('fruits', 'animals')

d = defaultdict(list)
for x in X:
    for f in filter:
        if re.search(fr'\b{f}\b', x):
            d[f].append(x)

for k, v in d.items():
    with open(f'{k}.csv', 'w') as fi:
        for y in v:
            fi.write(y)
```